# Remove Language Block from Default.xml

Tags: magento2, php

I have this code here,

```
 <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="switch/languages.phtml">
 <arguments>
  <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
  </arguments>
 </block>
```

I want to disable this but it looks different from simply just adding,

```
<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
```

how do disable this from showing up on the website in the header? I'm not sure where to add referenceBlock

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code to :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
```

Run Command to clear cache : `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
```

Please clear cache and check this will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove this from your backend don't need to customize your code.

> **first**, go to your adminhtml->stores->settings->All Stores
>
> now open your store views and set status "disable".